# Managing OS's Wifi Settings using code - Android

Tags: android, operating-system, wifi, android-wifi

I want to design an app which takes the information of configured networks in the device and stores them in a file. When my app is launched, it directs me to the Wifi Settings page of the device. I want to store the password associated with the networks as entered by the user. Also, when user adds any network manually, it should store the entered parameters in the file including password entered. Can I get the values user entered somehow?
Is this possible in any way?? I don't want to design the whole Wifi Settings for this thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had go on designing the whole stuff. The OS doesnt provide you with secret data like passwords! It was so silly of me!